# What is a replacement for tf.losses.absolute_difference

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

My question is about in `TF2.0`. There is no `tf.losses.absolute_difference()` function and also there is no `tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN` attribute.

What should I use instead?
Is there a list of deleted `TF` functions in `TF2` and perhaps their replacement.

This is `TF1.x` code which does not run with `TF2`:

```py
result = tf.losses.absolute_difference(a,b,reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.MEAN)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can access this function via `tf.compat.v1`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

labels = tf.constant([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]])
predictions = tf.constant([[0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]])

res = tf.compat.v1.losses.absolute_difference(labels,
                                              predictions,
                                              reduction=tf.compat.v1.losses.Reduction.MEAN)
print(res.numpy()) # 0.6666667
```

Or you could implement it yourself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import losses_utils

def absolute_difference(labels, predictions, weights=1.0, reduction='mean'):
    if reduction == 'mean':
        reduction_fn = tf.reduce_mean
    elif reduction == 'sum':
        reduction_fn = tf.reduce_sum
    else:
        # You could add more reductions
        pass
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    predictions = tf.cast(predictions, tf.float32)
    losses = tf.abs(tf.subtract(predictions, labels))
    weights = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(weights), tf.float32)
    res = losses_utils.compute_weighted_loss(losses,
                                             weights,
                                             reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)

    return reduction_fn(res, axis=None)

res = absolute_difference(labels, predictions)
print(res.numpy()) # 0.6666667
```

Comment: thanks, so i can go forward, but what to use in future if tf.compat.v1 will no longer be available?

Comment: `TF` team doesn't have plans to remove `tf.compat.v1`  in the foreseeable future. But in any case, you could implement it yourself. See updated answer.